# Apache Flink: How to access a broadcast variable in a ReduceFunction?

Tags: apache-flink

I have a DataSet with one entry. This one value (a threshold) i need inside a reduce function. The flink documentation shows how to broadcast a dataset to a map function with:

```
data.map.withBroadcastSet(dataSetToBroadcast, "broadcastSetName");
```

and access it inside the map function with:

```
@Override
public void open() {
  Collection<Integer> broadcastSet = getRuntimeContext().getBroadcastVariable("broadcastSetName");
}
```

It appears this is only possible for RichMapFunctions but i would like to access this broadcast variable inside a Reduce function. When i write the open function inside my reduce function i get the error "Method does not override method from its superclass".

I know i could receive the broadcast inside the map function prior to my reduce, but then i would have to add it to every entry in the dataset, which is overhead. Also i am using a flatMapFunction where the open function is also not present.

I also dont want to .collect my one value in order to pass it into the reduce function.

Does someone know an alternate way of making my one value accessable inside the reduce function?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Broadcast set are accessed via the `RuntimeContext`. A `RuntimeContext` can be obtained by calling `RichFunction.getRuntimeContext()`.

Flink provides "rich" variants for most function interfaces, including `RichReduceFunction`.

Just implement a `RichReduceFunction` and you have access to all functionality of the `RuntimeContext`.